# Publishing ends up publishing many Components and runs out of memory

Tags: tridion

We have noticed that component publishing takes a long time.

The component we are trying to publish has pdf's and jpg's in it. It also has links to other components.

Looking at the logs we found that publisher is trying to publish multimedia items from the component and also MM components from the linked components. The linked components have more linked components.

Some components publish after a long time and **some fail throwing memory exception**.

Is this a bug in Tridion? Has anyone ran into this issue before?

Comment: Small clarification - (text) components don't necessarily *contain* multimedia. They either have component links to multimedia (mm) components or have rich text fields that have *links to* mm. Multimedia components *do* "have" binary files, but only one upload per mm component. The distinction matters because binary publishing isn't automatic, it starts with template logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design, if you want to prevent SDL Tridion resolving these additional items, you will need to modify the instructions that are sent to the Publisher. If you are using SDL Tridion 2009 or earlier, you will need to do this using an event system. If you are on version 2011 or greater, you can take advantage of the new Custom Resolvers. Perhaps you can specify which version you are using.

If you are on 2011, take a look at this article on Custom Resolvers: http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/a-custom-resolver-in-practice

If you are on 2009, you may find this Event sample handy

```
public void OnComponentPublishPre(Component Component, IXMLDOMDocument2 publishInstruction)
{
    //Code to prevent publishing linked components

    XmlNode nodePropagateLinks = (XmlNode)publishInstruction.selectSingleNode("ResolveComponentLinks");
    if (nodePropagateLinks == null)
    {
        IXMLDOMNode nodeResolveLinks = publishInstruction.createNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ResolveComponentLinks", "http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0");
        nodeResolveLinks.text = "false";
        publishInstruction.documentElement.appendChild(nodeResolveLinks);

    }
}
```

Comment: Chris,We are still on Tridion 2009

Comment: Tridion 2009 can use Custom Resolvers too, it was introduced in that version. http://nunolinhares.blogspot.com/2011/10/tridion-publisher-and-custom-resolvers.html

Comment: Thanks Nuno. I came across your blog and was helpful. Its good to know that same code will work in 2011

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed quite common that publishing a "well connected" Component can trigger an avalanche of items to be included in that publish action. Tridion in this case often takes an all or nothing approach when determining which linked items to include.

If you want more control over what gets published, you should consider writing a custom resolver as described here: http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/a-custom-resolver-in-practice

Answer (score 2):

The avalanche Frank refers generally comes from a mix of 3 parts:

- Binary Publishing
- Dynamic Templates
- Used By items

**Binary Publishing**

Your *templates* publish multimedia items typically with:

- `addbinary()`
- the older `publishbinary()` (in XSLT component templates), and/or
- `Publish Binaries in Package` template building block (TBB), which is part of the `Default Finish Actions` TBB.

If we skip this, authors need to publish multimedia separately, usually with a dynamic component template.

**Per Dynamic Template**

Multiple dynamic component templates could publish binaries for each dynamic component presentation. Three dynamic templates could mean three times as many (binary) publish requests. Also, any given template *could* publish binaries in other components if your logic gathers up those links.

**"Used By" Controls Propagation**
The *linked-to* items should not publish (except binaries per above). It's the other way around--already published items *using* your item get published. This includes pages that have the item or components *linking to* your item.

**How to Check**

- `Where Used` will show what items are using your item.
- When publishing an item, the `Show Items to Publish` option should match the above.

In addition to extending the resolver, look into finding the right item(s) to publish. For example, instead of publishing components linked from a page, have authors publish the page or *linking* (not linked to) component.