# Configuring custom resolvers on Tridion 2009

Tags: tridion, tridion2009

Rumor has it (see [Publishing ends up publishing many Components and runs out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023424/publishing-ends-up-publishing-many-components-and-runs-out-of-memory) for example) that custom resolvers are available in Tridion 2009. My question: how can you configure one without a TridionContentManager.config? Or am I completely off track and DOES 2009 come with this config file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my 2009 test system it's there (in the same location as 2011).

`<Tridion Home>/config/Tridion.ContentManager.config`

Comment: So I was off track. Thanks for the quick response.